# How to prevent computer from overheating

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, 17.10, shutdown, overheating

I am new to Ubuntu, using 17.10, GNOME 3.26.2.

When I work on Windows 7, there was no problem

But my computer shuts down when I work on Ubuntu.

I have cleaned the computer so I think there is a problem with the OS.

When only Chrome is running, sensors shows this:

[image: psensor image]

I use dell N5110 (i7, 6GB RAM) and ekstra monitor. When I work with android studio, the computer freezes for 2-3 minutes. Also, when something is being dragged from PC monitor to the other monitor or vice versa, it sometimes freezes for 1 min. In addition, GNOME sent an error to server yesterday. Maybe you can help me. If I can't solve it, I have to change OS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep it safe! Do not power on! Keep it off! Maybe any logs here like "syslog"? Huh?!

Comment: Do you want to see syslog? If you want it, which part do you want? it is long.

Comment: I checked temp, while cpu was 64C, computer turned itself off.

Comment: GPUs also have shutoff thresholds around 100C...it's not your CPU.

Comment: What video driver is selected?

Comment: I did not install driver because drivers doesn't support linux into dell web site.

Comment: Add the output of `sudo lshw -c video` to the question.

Comment: I guess, it's nVidia GeForce GT 525M inside. Get nVidia drivers first into Ubuntu.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-390

Comment: And about syslog. It is not needed to post it all syslog. Check what is wrong, check events with date/time when it's freeze, search for errors or something strange.

Comment: Your suggestion killed my 2 hours. I couldn't run computer.

Comment: Did you verify you had an NVidia card first?  Did you check to see what vdieo driver was already installed?  There is another post on here suggesting the more recent nvidia drivers were causing heat issues and that the nvidia-340 solved it.  Start with identifying what you have first.

Comment: Thank you for help but i didn't find any solution so I changed my OS to win 8.1. Now, I am good and I don't have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, because I don't have the ability to comment yet, but have you checked your BIOS for some shutdown / power state / suspend parameter that Windows might be overriding but Linux isn't? It's weird how it shuts down at 64 degrees, which is nothing at all temperature wise. Try a different Live distro and hammer it with a benchmarking tool. That should hopefully give you some clues.

Comment: 65°C is the datasheet maximum for some CPUs, and the default setting probably honour that.

Comment: That's really interesting...and really low!

Comment: i7-2670QM Starts throttling at 100C, plenty of room.

Comment: That's more like what I'd expect.